# Gurobi: checking intermediate solutions of linear program against a threshold

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to solve a set of inequalities of the form A x ≤ b together with cx ≥ d. I know that solving the LP max qx. A x ≤ b for any positive q (non-negative in at least one position) gives the point-wise maximal vector x satisfying A x ≤ b. However, as I am only interested in the existence of a point that additionally satisfies cx ≥ d I would like to speed up the procedure.

My approach is to optimze the LP "max cx. A x ≤ b" using primal simplex with Gurobi and checking in a callback whether the current objective is greater than d and, if it is, calling model.terminate().

However, after terminating, I cannot retrieve the last basis of the optimization. I have tried changing the objective function to 0, and then calling model.optimize(), hoping that it would store the last computed basis (which was feasible), and hence terminate immediately. But it seems that changing the objective function makes the model forget the computed basis.

This is true even if I disable the presolver completely.
How can I retrieve this intermediate solution from the model? Is there another approach that solves my problem?

For a related discussion, see:
https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360050215531-Checking-intermediate-solutions-against-a-threshold-Linear-programming?flash_digest=52cc3a8fc334816d3d57477c5f89c64a8d6ba780

Comment: Did you try the barrier method on the original problem? (may be after disabling concurrent LP so you can use all threads for the barrier method).